# Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.XMLValidateTask was not found

Tags: java, ant

I'm facing an issue with Ant. I'm using xmlvalidate tag in my build.xml.

```
        <xmlvalidate file="${basedir}/**/@{filename}" failonerror="true">
            <attribute name="http://xml.org/sax/features/validation" value="true" />
            <attribute name="http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema" value="true" />
            <attribute name="http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces" value="true" />
        </xmlvalidate>
```

I'm getting the below error

```
Problem: failed to create task or type xmlvalidate
[ERROR] Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.XMLValidateTask was not found.
[ERROR] This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
[ERROR] Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
[ERROR] -ANT_HOME\lib
```

I've explored a lot on this and tried few suggestions:
   1) I've searched for the jar file(added ant-optional-1.5.1.jar) which contains org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.XMLValidateTask and added to the ANT_HOME\lib folder as it's specified in the error. 
2)Right now I'm using ant 1.9.7 and updated to 1.10.5.

with either of the option I didn't succeeded.

From the error all I understood is some jar is missing..

Please help on this issue. Thanks for your time in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ant optional jar to the classpath and refer that classpath.

```
<property name='lib.dir' value='lib' />

<path id='classpath'>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>
```